# ngrok warning page does not dissappear when using redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ngrok, request-headers, actiondispatch

I have a shopify checkout proxy app which I am developing and testing on ngrok. Whenever the `redirect_to` command is used to redirect to an action within my checkout app using the proxy URL. The ngrok error warning comes and does not go away no matter how many times I click on visit site.

I have tried updating the request and response headers with `ngrok-skip-browser-warning` but still no luck, since the headers are coming from a proxy URL.